# Can`t Open a connection stream

Tags: ios, stream, connection, wifi, exc-bad-access

Hi I`m trying to establish a connection to a port, but whenever the code bellow runs, I get the following error :  thread 1 exc_bad_access

Thanks in Advance

```
NSString *theTry=@"192.168.3.170:23"; 
    NSInputStream *iStream;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:theTry];

    [iStream initWithURL:url];
    [iStream setDelegate:self];
    [iStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [iStream open];
```

Comment: At which line do you get the crash?

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:theTry]; //on this line

Comment: See what happens if you leave only the string: @"192.168.3.170" or replace it with a normal URL, instead of an IP address

Comment: I have tried replacing it with @"192.168.3.170", and got the same error. Replacing it with a normal URL won`t help, as I`m trying to connect to a native controller that has its own static IP